# How to Replace Nulls with Integers Conditionally Pyspark Dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe

I am trying to (within pyspark/spark). Specifically, the dataframe looks like this:

```
ID    response_variable    id_name
id_1   NULL                 "randomidDKHFD"
id_2   NULL                 NULL
id_3   NULL                 "randomid86438"
```

I want to be able to transform the dataframe so that whenever id_name has a non-NULL entry, response_variable becomes 1. Thus, in this example:

```
ID    response_variable    in_data
id_1   1                 "randomidDKHFD"
id_2   NULL                NULL
id_3   1                 "randomid86438"
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `withColumn` and `when` to do this.

Python:

```
yourDf.withColumn("response_variable", when(col("id_name").isNotNull(), lit(1)).otherwise(col("response_variable")))
```

Scala:

```
yourDf.withColumn("response_variable", when(col("id_name").isNotNull, lit(1)).otherwise(col("response_variable")))
```